# Sliding Up Panel (Java to Kotlin)

Tags: java, android, kotlin

How can I display panel states of SlidingUpPanel in Kotlin?

I want to use https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel library, following this tutorial:

http://www.devexchanges.info/2015/05/making-sliding-up-panel-like-google.html

and the result should look like this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g464fp-2dQU

The code in Java from tutorial link:

```
private SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelSlideListener onSlideListener() {
    return new SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelSlideListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPanelSlide(View view, float v) {
            textView.setText("panel is sliding");
        }

        @Override
        public void onPanelCollapsed(View view) {
            textView.setText("panel Collapse");
        }

        @Override
        public void onPanelExpanded(View view) {
            textView.setText("panel expand");
        }

        @Override
        public void onPanelAnchored(View view) {
            textView.setText("panel anchored");
        }

        @Override
        public void onPanelHidden(View view) {
            textView.setText("panel is Hidden");
        }
    };
}
```

The converted code from Java to Kotlin (I put toast from anko library instead of textView):

```
private fun onSlideListener(): SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelSlideListener {
    return object : SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelSlideListener {
        override fun onPanelSlide(view: View, v: Float) {
            toast("panel is sliding")
        }

        override fun onPanelCollapsed(view: View) {
            toast("panel Collapse")
        }

        override fun onPanelExpanded(view: View) {
            toast("panel expand")
        }

        override fun onPanelAnchored(view: View) {
            toast("panel anchored")
        }

        override fun onPanelHidden(view: View) {
            toast("panel is Hidden")
        }
    }
}
```

In Java code, in onCreate method, I have:

```
slidingLayout.setPanelSlideListener(onSlideListener());
```

which doesn't seems to work in Kotlin, because the methods I have are Click, Drag, Hover, Key and Touch (listeners).

I guess other good approach could be to implement

```
SlidingPaneLayout.PanelSlideListener
```

on my class, but I still couldn't make it work.

Any solution to find up if the panel is displayed or hidden in Kotlin?

Comment: methods doesn't have 'override' specified, but it should have been a compile-time error

Answer (score 1):

You need to  load up the Slidinglayout.

```
private lateinit var slidingLayout: SlidingUpPanelLayout
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false).also {
        slidingLayout = it.findViewById(R.id.sliding_Layout)
    }
}
```

than you check for the PanelState

```
if (slidingLayout.panelState == SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState.HIDDEN)
```

You also have the states ANCHORED, EXPANDED, COLLAPSED, DRAGGING

If you want to set up the Listener in Kotlin I have done it like This.

```
slidingLayout.addPanelSlideListener(object : SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelSlideListener {
        override fun onPanelSlide(panel: View?, slideOffset: Float) {
            TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }

        override fun onPanelStateChanged(panel: View?, previousState: SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState?, newState: SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState?) {
           TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }
    })
```